# Is there a way to exclude specific hosts from a Nagios hostgroup?

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios, centos6

I have a Nagios server which includes many `hostgroups`.
One of these `hostgroups` include a server which I'd like to exclude from being checked for one specific Nagios `Check` but I want it to keep being a member of the `hostgroup` so it may get checked for all the other `checks` that the `hostgroup` is checked for.
Is there an option of `exclude` or something like that which can help me achieve my goal?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Haven't yet tried it with hosts, but with hostgroups, prefixing with a `!` works. I use this for running a different load check on busy servers:

```
define host {
    use         physical-host
    host_name   busy-host.example.com
    alias       busy-host.example.com
    address     10.43.16.1
    hostgroups  linux,centos,ldap,http,busy
}

define host {
    use           physical-host
    host_name     normal-host.example.com
    alias         narmal-host.example.com
    address       10.43.1.1
    hostgroups    linux,centos,dns,proxy,ldap,hp,http,puppetmaster
}

define service {
    use                   generic-service
    hostgroup_name        linux,!busy
    service_description   Load
    check_command         check_snmp_load
}

define service {
    use                   generic-service
    hostgroup_name        busy
    service_description   Load
    check_command         check_snmp_load_busy
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Add the specific host with a `!` prefix in the service definition.  The service check below will apply to all hosts in `agroup` apart from `ahost`.

```
define service {
    hostgroup_name   agroup
    host_name       !ahost   
    service_description Shared NFS mount
    check_command check_nrpe!check_shared_mount
    use generic-service
```

}

Comment: is it possible to achive this in the host file instead of where the service is defined?

Answer (score 1):

You can create one or more hostgroup(s) for excluding things - add it/them to hosts where you want to exclude one or more checks - naming it something like ~no-ipv6 or ~no-ssl or whatever makes it pretty obvious what it's meant to do.

Apply the exclude hostgroup to the host(s) you want to exclude in addition to the normal one(s) it's a member of.

In the Service description, where the hostgroup name(s) that have that service applied are defined, use an ! (in this context, meaning "not") to exclude them.

So if you have a hostgroup "webservers", where some hosts can't do ssl, you might create another hostgroup "~no-ssl". In the services.cfg file, on the service definition that checks https, under hostgroup name, you would put `webservers,!~no-ssl`

The effect of this would be that all hosts in the hostgroup webservers are checked against SSL - but those that are *also* in hostgroup ~no-ssl won't have SSL checked. Handy!

If there are some checks you want ALL hosts to undergo, aside from a few, you can use `*,!~exclusion`

This abstraction is tremendously useful; even more so is using templates to assign (or exclude) a whole bunch of services to a type of host (which then means you can use the hostgroups definitions on each host simply for "extra" additional checks you want to run, or specific exclusions - i.e. template is the "norm", hostgroups are the exception(s)).